# Assembly GDB Print String

Tags: string, assembly, gdb, printing

So in assembly I declare the following String:

```
Sample db "This is a sample string",0
```

In GDB I type "p Sample" (without quotes) and it spits out 0x73696854. I want the actual String to print out. So I tried "printf "%s", Sample" (again, without quotes) and it spits out "Cannot access memory at address 0x73696854."

Short version:
How do I print a string in GDB?

Answer (score 18):

My teacher just emailed me back. For anyone wondering:

```
p(char[20]) Sample
```

Where 20 is the number of characters to print out.

To print a C-style `NUL`-terminated string, you should also be able to do this:

```
print (char*) &Sample
printf "%s", &Sample
```

Comment: Not sure if you're still active but you could accept your own answer to make it is easier to find

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue! Try this one:

```
x/s &Sample # prints the whole string
```

"x" - Stands generally for examining data.

For a signle character you could youse this code

```
x/c &Sample # prints: "T"
```

And if you want see multiple characters you could give the number of wished characters

```
x/3c &Sample # prints: "T" "h" "i"
```

Comment: Actually it prints the ASCII value of the character then the character itself. So `x/3c &Sample # prints:  0x7fffffffdc52: 48 'T' 104 'h' 105 'i'`